# Read a CSV file and Progressively AddUp the values of a Specific column in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to read all the rows of a specific column in a CSV file using powershell script.
Then add the values progressively until current row and then updated the sum in a new column.

For example: in the sample below I want to read all the values in column COLUMNB then add it progressively and update it in PROG_COLB
Likewise I want to do it for COLUMNC

Sample CSV file:

```
"RANK","COLUMNB","COLUMNC"
"5","510","10"
"4","500","60"
"3","120","100"
"0","600","200"
"-1","1000","40"
```

Expected Output:

```
"RANK","COLUMNB","COLUMNC","PROG_COLB","PROG_COLC"
"5","510","10","510","10"
"4","500","60","1010","70"
"3","120","100","1130","170"
"0","600","200","1730","370"
"-1","1000","40","2730","410"
```

I tried few things but couldn't get the expected output, I was able to read a specific column and I managed to put it inside a hash-table then I got stuck.
Any advice on how to solve this riddle would be of great help.

```
$csv =Import-Csv .\stats.csv 
$hash_COLB = @{​​​​}​​​​
$hash_COLC = @{​​​​}​​​​
foreach($item in $csv)
{​​​​
[int]$prog_COLB=[int]$prog_COLB+[int]$item.COLUMNB
[int]$prog_COLC=[int]$prog_COLC+[int]$item.COLUMNC
$hash_COLB.add($item.RANK,$prog_COLB)
$hash_COLC.add($item.RANK,$prog_COLC)
}​​​​

$hash_COLB
$hash_COLC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two variables for the running counts of the values in COLUMNB and COLUMNC.

```
$runningCount_B = 0
$runningCount_C = 0
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\sample.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $runningCount_B += [int]$_.COLUMNB
    $runningCount_C += [int]$_.COLUMNC
    # output a new object with all columns from the original, and added running counts
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'PROG_COLB'; Expression = {$runningCount_B}}, 
                          @{Name = 'PROG_COLC'; Expression = {$runningCount_C}}
}

# output on console screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\new_sample.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output as CSV:

```
"RANK","COLUMNB","COLUMNC","PROG_COLB","PROG_COLC"
"5","510","10","510","10"
"4","500","60","1010","70"
"3","120","100","1130","170"
"0","600","200","1730","370"
"-1","1000","40","2730","410"
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward (IMO) and easy to read solution uses `ForEach-Object` to iterate over the rows and output a `PSCustomObject` that has the calculated new rows.

```
$sumColB = 0
$sumColC = 0

$newCsv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
    $sumColB += $_.COLUMNB
    $sumColC += $_.COLUMNC

    # This is the output of this loop iteration. PowerShell automatically adds it to $newCsv.
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        RANK      = $_.RANK
        COLUMNB   = $_.COLUMNB
        COLUMNC   = $_.COLUMNC
        PROG_COLB = $sumColB
        PROG_COLC = $sumColC
    }
}
```

Another way is to use `Select-Object` with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1), which is less readable, but has the advantage of being reusable.

```
Function Get-ColumnSum( [ref] $var, $columnName ) { 
    $var.Value += $_.$columnName   # Add the value of the column named by $columnName
    $var.Value                     # output
}

$sumB = 0
$sumC = 0

$newCsv = $csv | Select-Object *, 
                   @{ name = 'PROG_COLB'; expression = { Get-ColumnSum ([ref] $sumB) COLUMNB } }, 
                   @{ name = 'PROG_COLC'; expression = { Get-ColumnSum ([ref] $sumC) COLUMNC } }
```

First we define a function `Get-ColumnSum` that accumulates the value of the given column in a variable passed by reference and outputs the current sum.

Then in the `Select-Object` call we call this function from the script blocks of the calculated columns.

Passing variables by reference is necessary because of PowerShell scoping rules. If you modify a variable in a nested scope, only a copy of the variable would be modified. With pass-by reference we can directly modify the given variable.